# How to pass data directly to final database in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

Some of the data are just passed as is from the staging database to final database.

Is there a way to load data directly into the final database?
The goal is to reduce the total time processing during harmonization.

Answer (score 1):

The operational data hub uses MarkLogic content pump to load data into MarkLogic. You can control the destination database in MarkLogic content pump by setting the `database` parameter. Set the `database` to be the name of final database and run MarkLogic content pump in the command line.

Alternatively you can set the `port` for the app server associated with the final database.

Comment: It's much easier to set the -database parameter to the name of the database you want to insert into. Any port can insert into any database.

Comment: Thanks Rob S.  and @ElijahBernstein-Cooper for your insights! I am currently using datahub for harmonization. What if I want to load some but not all of the element values of an XML directly to final database? Is that possible?

Comment: @Ryan What does that mean? You want to just load some elements instead of whole document ? The case can be you might have to update only some element of a document and then have to load few documents out of total documents.

Comment: @Ryan it may be worth asking a new question about filtering elements during ingest.